# ANDROID - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId()

Tags: android

Buenas comunidad, acabo de encontrarme con este error nada más arrancar la app en el dispositivo físico, sin cambiar nínguna parte del código principal en donde arranca la app ha saltado este error, no indica ninguna línea de código en donde esté el error, aún así paso los datos del `logcat`

> 10-30 20:05:50.772 16897-16919/es.aandg.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>
> Process: es.aandg.demo, PID: 16897
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId(Native Method)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.(HttpTracker.java:191)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.(HttpTracker.java:186)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker.trackConnection(HttpTracker.java:280)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:49)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnection$.(HttpsURLConnection$.java:50)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnectionHelper(HttpURLWrapper.java:40)
>
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnection(HttpURLWrapper.java:55)
>
> at com.facebook.GraphRequest.createConnection(GraphRequest.java:1407)
>
> at com.facebook.GraphRequest.toHttpConnection(GraphRequest.java:1067)
>
> at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1155)
>
> at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1131)
>
> at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1115)
>
> at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1090)
>
> at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:984)
>
> at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:223)
>
> at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$100(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:53)
>
> at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:132)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Adrían, te saludo, no crees que es importante agregar tu código?, comentar con que estas trabajando, Retrofit acaso? aporta más información? revisa [ask].

Comment: @Jorgesys hola jorge, este error ha aparecido sin más y no apunta a ningún código en la app. Si pusiese el código sería bastante ya que no sé donde puede estar el error. No estoy trabajando con Retrofit

Comment: Sin realizar ningun cambio? busca en tu LogCat "Caused by"

Comment: @Jorgesys ese es todo el error desde que crashea la app. Esta app lanza un main activity el cual tiene varios fragments, el cambio de código cuando ha sido esto ha sido en uno de esos fragments, pero en ningún momento estoy llamando a esos fragments desde la app principal, por lo que el error no debería de darse si es que hubiese un error en la activity principal porque ahí no he hecho ningún cambio, y a parte el error no tiene nada que ver con algo que haya hecho ya que estaba usando FirebaseStorage

Answer (score 2):

Me ocurrió lo mismo luego de querer usar Android Profiler.
Al parecer Advance Debugging no funciona bien con las dependencias de facebook.

La solución es deshabilitar esa opción en: `Run Configurations > Profiling > Destildar enable advance profiling`